# Reaction Delete channel | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, embed

I am making a ticket system with discord.js

I tried to when a member reacts to the message with the emoji, the ticket will close, but after running it, it shows an error

```
if (reaction.emoji.name == '') {
    if(!reaction.channel.name.includes("ticket")) return;
    channel.delete()
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you didn't specify the error I can see that you never defined "channel".
If you want to delete the channel in which the reaction was added use:

```js
reaction.message.channel.delete();
```